# EnvoyFilter disable Distributed Tracing not working

Tags: openshift, istio, envoyproxy, distributed-tracing, istio-sidecar

I have the following set-up and use-case:

- **Openshift Version 4.12**
- **Openshift ServiceMesh Version 2.4.1**
- **Istio Version 1.16.5**
- **Envoy Proxy Version 1.24.8**

We noticed that during outbound requests (when a request is leaving the pod), the EnvoyProxy is adding W3C(OpenTelemetry) Tracing Headers to the request if they are not available. This is a behaviour that we do not want, because it creates confusions in some use-cases.

To mitigate this, I tried to create several EnvoyFilter to disable the HttpConnectionManager's Tracing, but without any luck.

These are the documentation pages I was following:

- **[HttpConnectionManager.Tracing](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.24.8/api-v3/extensions/filters/network/http_connection_manager/v3/http_connection_manager.proto.html#extensions-filters-network-http-connection-manager-v3-httpconnectionmanager-tracing)**
- **[Runtime](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.24.8/configuration/http/http_conn_man/runtime)**

Below you can find the two EnvoyFilters I created based on those documentations, bot neither of them seems to work:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: disable-tracing
  namespace: <namespace>
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      context: ANY 
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager" 
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
          tracing:
            global_enabled:
              value: 0
            client_enabled:
              value: 0
            random_sampling:
              value: 0
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: disable-tracing
  namespace: <namespace>
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      context: ANY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager" 
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
          tracing:
            client_sampling:
              value: 0
            random_sampling:
              value: 0
            overall_sampling:
              value: 0
```

After creating any of those EnvoyFilter, and restarting the Pod so that the Envoy config will be merged with that of the Envoyfilter, I still see stiff in the Envoy configuration

```json
"filters": [
                    {
                      "name": "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager",
                      "typed_config": {
                        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager",
                        "http_filters": [
                          {
                            "name": "envoy.filters.http.router",
                            "typed_config": {
                              "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "route_config": {
                          "virtual_hosts": [
                            {
                              "domains": [
                                "*"
                              ],
                              "name": "backend",
                              "routes": [
                                {
                                  "match": {
                                    "prefix": "/healthz/ready"
                                  },
                                  "route": {
                                    "cluster": "agent"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "stat_prefix": "agent",
                        "tracing": {}
                      }
```

As you can see, both the filters are matching, as well as the typed_config, however, the **tracing** part is still empty.

Does anyone have any suggestions/ideas of what I might be missing? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tracing headers (e.g. `x-b3-sampled`, spanid, tracid) by setting the following pod annotation:

```
     proxy.istio.io/config: |
            tracing: {}
```